# Wordpress pages have canonical entry to another website caused by Yoast

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I originally posted this question on the main stackoverflow site, but was advised to delete it there and repost it here. If this is still not the right place, please let me know.

We have a Wordpress blog at https://www.rephunter.net/blog/. Many of the pages have a canonical link to another completely unrelated blog that I run personally, but has no connection to the blog in question.

For example, on the page https://www.rephunter.net/blog/keep-the-ball-rolling/, the following entry appears, with the actual site name replaced with asterisks:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.******.com/blog/keep-the-ball-rolling/" />
```

So the result is that the canonical entry is not pointing to our website at [www.rephunter.net](http://www.rephunter.net), but instead is going elsewhere.

I have searched for how canonical entries might be controlled, and the main articles all talk about Yoast. In fact we use Yoast, but we have never set up canonical entries at all.

As another measure, I grepped the entire code base but could not find anything in the code.

As a final step I looked into the Yoast tables in the database. I found 17 entries that had in the permalink column references to the wrong URL. I checked the permalink for those pages, but they are not pointing to the wrong website but to the proper website.

As a test, I manually changed a permalink anyways and rechecked that table--it still was pointing to the wrong website.

Looking further into Yoast, I was able to run the "wp yoast index" command from the command line. The tables were re-indexed. However, the 17 entries are still pointing to the wrong website.

As a next step, I deactivated Yoast. After that those canonical entries pointing to the wrong site were gone.

I reactivated Yoast hoping that it might have fixed itself, but unfortunately the bad canonical links came back.

So the problem appears to be in Yoast, and somewhere it has got information about the wrong blog.

As an additional test, I manually updated the Yoast indexable table to change the permalink column on the 17 rows from the wrong website to the correct website. Then reactivated Yoast.

After those steps, the canonical entry is now correct. So the immediate issue is corrected. However, I would like to know how Yoast was corrupted, as I suspect the problem might recur.

In fact, the issue regressed a couple of months later.

It was suggested that I ask for support on Yoast support site. I did that, and was advised there is a built in method for correcting the issue. That method is as follows:

1. Install and activate the Yoast Test Helper plugin
2. Go to Tools > Yoast Test
3. Hit the “Reset Indexables and Migrations” button
4. Under SEO → Tools, click the "Start SEO Data Optimization" button.

This procedure does in fact correct the issue.

However, after a couple of months, the issue regresses. Running that procedure does again correct it.

So the bottom line question is what causes this to happen? At the Yoast site they suggested that "Typically an issue like this is caused when values of URLs from a previous location are retained. To resolve this, we’d recommend trying [the steps quoted above]."

I have also posted to the Yoast website about the regression.

I am not sure what that means or how to correct the periodic recurrence.

Comment: Are the sites sharing the same wordpress install or database? Right now both domains are showing the exact same content for me on every single URL. Also, the "unrelated' blog domain is serving the wrong cert, for rephunter.com, so the browser is displaying a certificate error. Not sure these are related to the problem but something about this configuration seems off.

Comment: Have you looked in your .htaccess file?  Yoast puts some configuration items in there.  Maybe it's pulling a string from the configuration files.  When you say it reverts, is it only for content published in the last few months, or does it revert for content that existed prior to the helper plugin being ran?

Comment: The other site appears to be one of your own domains.  It has its DNS NS records set to the NS records for your main domain.  It resolves to an IP address in the same c-block.   It serves the same content.   But you are censoring the domain name in your question like you don't believe it is your own site?

Comment: @drew010: The sites are not using the same Wordpress install or database.

Comment: @Trebor: I looked at the .htaccess files of both sites. Nothing suspicious there. Seems to revert about once per month. It started the cross linking a couple of days ago. The fix procedure describe above fixed it again.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - yes as stated in the original question, both sites are mine.